# Sencha - Unable to create sencha app

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am unable to generate app using SenchaCmd 5.1.3.61. I am getting following error. Can someone let me know if I am doing something wrong or missing anything?

**Console Output:**

D:\wamp\www\SenchaWorkspace>sencha generate app SenchaApp SenchaApp

Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61

[INF] Workspace does not have framework null at D:\wamp\www\SenchaWorkspace ...
copying

[ERR] Failed to determine framework name.  Please ensure this command was issued
 from either a framework or application directory

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing the `-sdk` argument.

Try:

```
sencha -sdk /path/to/ext generate app SenchaApp SenchaApp
```

Comment: From where I can get/download sdk for extjs 5 framework?

Comment: You can downlod the framework from support.sencha.com